# Trim leading whitespace using awk command

Tags: awk

I have seen the other examples and posts but just can't seem to get this working.
I have some lparstat output which looks like:

```
Partition  Number                           :  1
Type                                       :  Dedicated-SMT
Mode                                       : Capped
Entitled  Capacity                          : 4,00
Partition  Group-ID                         : 32769
Shared Pool  ID                             : -
```

I would like to get the Capped value.

I have the following command however need to elimanate the leading whitespace:

```
cat lparstat.out | egrep '^Mode' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'
```

Any suggestion on how to modify the awk command appreciated. I don't want to pipe to sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F '  *: ' '$1=="Mode"{print $2}' lparstat.out
```

or with a regex:

```
awk -F ': ' '/^Mode/{print $2}' lparstat.out
```

Output:

```
Capped
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested this and it works:

```
cat lparstat.out | egrep '^Mode' | awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '{ print $2 }'
```

This changes the field separator to `:` followed by zero or more spaces or tab characters.

Comment: Thanks - Marked Cyrus as answer since it does the same in a shorter command

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
awk -F ":" '/^Mode/ {gsub(/ /,"");print $2}' lparstat.out
```

Output:

```
Capped
```